# how to use matchbox keyboard using subprocess in raspberry pi?

Tags: subprocess

I want to run my code on raspberry pi which has a touchscreen attached to it. The GUI is made using pyqt5 and I want to pop up the system onscreen keyboard when the entry is focused.

tried many things but didn't get how to use this.

Comment: Progman ok, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my problem is solved, this is for the future in case anyone has doubt in pyqt, you can use qlineedit selectionchanged object, for eg. mobile_entry.selectionChanged.connect(self.create_keyboard). and in create keyboard function you should do this >> subprocess.Popen(["onboard"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)